# How to resolve Argument of type 'number' is not assignable to parameter of type 'string' using angular?

Tags: angular, string, typescript, modulo

**My Code***

```
columnName(num: number) {
    for (var ret = '', a = 1, b = 26; (num -= a) >= 0; a = b, b *= 26) {
      ret = String.fromCharCode(parseInt((num % b) / a) + 65) + ret;
    }
    return ret;
  }
```

***I am getting error in String.fromCharCode(parseInt((num % b) / a) using modulos operator***

Comment: [The parseInt() function **parses a string** and returns an integer.](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_parseint.asp).

Answer (score 0):

just add `toString()` function before parsing:

```
 ret = String.fromCharCode(parseInt((num % b / a).toString()) + 65) + ret;
```

or you can use bitwise to get an integer number.

```
ret = String.fromCharCode(~~(num % b / a) + 65) + ret;
```